# Is there a way to play YouTube Videos (Embed) with Sound in Autoplay?

Tags: python, video, webview, youtube, streaming

First: Sorry for my Bad English, i give my best!

I work at my own "WallpaperEngine" and i create a PyWebView Window which loads a YouTube Embed Video URL. The URL looks like:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/-mwjpftcfqU?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=YKFy7Q8r8EU&muted=1

And it's working Fine. But is there a way to Play this with Sound? When i remove the "muted=1" the Autoplay doesnt work's. Any Idea's?

Thank You!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have blocked autoplay with sound. There is a permission a user needs to give in order to allow pages to autoplay it.